# strcat() implementation works but causes a core dump at the end

Tags: c, coredump, strcat

My implementation of `strcat(char*, const char*)` seems to work but then it causes a core dump.

`strcat()` implementation:

```
char* strcat(char* dest, const char* src)
{
    char* tmp = dest;
    while(*tmp) ++tmp ;
    while( (*tmp++ = *src++ ) != '\0') ;
    return (dest);
}
```

Code in `int main()` where I call strcat():

```
char arr3[] = "Mr. ";
char arr4[] = "Smith";
printf("Hello %s!", strcat(arr3, arr4));
```

It actually concatenated both strings and printed it out but still caused a core dump.

output : **Hello Mr. Smith!Aborted (core dumped)**

What did I do wrong?

Comment: Although old and you have accepted but read updated answer added some interesting details...

Comment: Okay, thanks. I will in a few seconds ;)

Comment: That's probably because when you don't specify a size, the array automatically chooses the ideal size to fit its contents. So `arr3` is 5 bytes long, and adding `"Smith"` requires a 10-byte string. Why it's a core dump rather than a segmentation fault, I cannot tell you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your program doing [**buffer overflow**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buffer_overflow)  at runs time, by `strcat(arr3, arr4)` because `arr3` size is just equals to length of `"Mr."` string , it has no extra memory space for extra chars (from `arr4`).

size of `arr3` should be atlest  string length of a `"Mr. " + "Smith" + 1`
(*extra 1 for string termination `\0` char*)

My Suggestion is use dynamic memory allocation for sufficient size buffer, do something like code below:

```
char arr3[] = "Mr. ";
char arr4[] = "Smith";
length = strlen(arr3) + strlen(arr4) + 1;  //cal-length (sufficient long buffer)
char* new_arr = malloc(length);  // allocate memory 
strcpy(new_arr, arr3);  // copy first string 
strcat(new_arr, arr4);  // then check your function to concat strings
```

**Reason of Core-Dump:**

In your code :

```
char arr3[] = "Mr. ";
```

The size of `arr2` is = length of string `"Mr."` length + `1`  (1 because of `\0`)  chars. The `strcat()` first moves `temp` pointers to point null in first while loop `while(*tmp) ++tmp ;`.

After that in second while loop `while( (*tmp++ = *src++ ) != '\0') ;`  you are trying to  accessing and assigning on memory that is not allocated ( my be out of your process control) and access a memory that you have not allocated is undefined behavior in C.

**Edit:**

In code  `arr3` is something like below in diagram, where `temp` points to `arr3` array:

```
                arr3

   temp          5   6  7  8    
  +-----+      +--+--+--+---+
  | 5   +----->|M |r |. |\0 |
  +-----+      +--+--+--+---+
```

when loop `while(*tmp) ++tmp ;`  breaks `temp` starts pointing to memory location `8` where null `\0` is stored,  like below diagram.

```
                arr3

   temp          5   6  7  8    
  +-----+      +--+--+--+---+
  | 8   |      |M |r |. |\0 |
  +-----+      +--+--+--+---+
     |                    ^
     +--------------------|
```

When you do `temp++`  in loop  `while( (*tmp++ = *src++ ) != '\0') ;` , `temp` increment to point to memory location `9` and onwards, but access and assigning on memory `9`, `10`.. is illegal because its not allocated. This causes OS kernel send a signal [core dump](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Core_dump) to the your process which caused the exception. (**interesting to note:** as OS detects memory right violation by a process -- An invalid access to valid memory gives: SIGSEGV And access to an invalid address gives: SIGBUS).

> [Program Error Signals:](http://www.cs.utah.edu/dept/old/texinfo/glibc-manual-0.02/library_21.html#SEC336)
>   When one of these program error signals terminates a process, it also
>   writes a core dump file which records the state of the process at the
>   time of termination. The core dump file is named `core' and is written
>   in whichever directory is current in the process at the time. (On the
>   GNU system, you can specify the file name for core dumps with the
>   environment variable COREFILE.) The purpose of core dump files is so
>   that you can examine them with a debugger to investigate what caused
>   the error.

If you allocates extra memory (as @JerryCoffin and @Paul R suggested) then you can access memory beyond `\0` (*memory location `8`*)  is no problem.

**Note:** If you not gives size at declaration then size of array will be equals to size of string e.g. in `char arr3[] = "Mr. ";` size is `5`. But if you give size explicitly as `char arr3[84] = "Mr. ";` then size of `aar3` will be `84` and initial memory contains `Mr.` then `0` in rest of all locations.

In my solution I completely allocate new memory blocks that is as large as both string `arr3` and `arr4` can be stored with null symbol using dynamic memory allocation (`malloc()` function). Additionally If you allocates dynamic memory using `ptr = malloc()` or `ptr = calloc()` then you should free memory explicitly when work done using `free(ptr)`.

Comment: So the only thing stopping me from going beyond the '\0' is the OS Kernel? On a machine without an OS, could I go beyond?

Comment: @Davlog Not `'\0'`, but beyond the allocated space. How can you run your simple C code on a machine without OS (second question is not valid).

Answer (score 2):

You haven't allocated any additional space in `str3` so attempting to append characters using `strcat` will overflow the allocated storage - change your code to e.g.:

```
char arr3[80] = "Mr. "; // <<< allocate additional storage for appending more characters
char arr4[] = "Smith";
printf("Hello %s!", strcat(arr3, arr4));
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem isn't with your `strcat`, but with how you're using/invoking it. You're writing past the end of the target array.

Change `arr3` to something like `char arr3[32] = "Mr. ";` and all will be well.

Comment: would it work if I use malloc() inside the function for dest?

Comment: @Davlog basic problem is that `arr3` is small, it has no extra space to accommodate extra chars from `arr4`, even if you allocates memory using `malloc()` it will you `strcat()` work if you allocate extra spaces

Comment: @Davlog: You could, for example, allocate a new block of memory as large as both input strings (+1 for a NUL terminator) and create a concatenated string there. That would be different from how `strcat` normally works though.