# C++ char* problems

Tags: c++

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    char *name="Siva",*str;
    for(int i=0;i<strlen(name);i++)
    {
        str[i]=name[i];
    }
    cout<<str;
    return 0;
}
```

The first program gives output Sivaœ> i.e siva with some garbage values....
But the second program show segmentation fault...Please help me to find out
exact answer...

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int i=0;
    char *name="Siva",*str;
    for(i=0;i<strlen(name);i++)
    {
        str[i]=name[i];
    }
    cout<<str;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What are you writing _to_? What does `str` point _at_?

Comment: What would you like an answer **too**? You have only described how your programs behave, not what the problem is, or what you *want* them to do, or what you *expect* them to do

Comment: Then how it gives answer for first case......

Comment: `char *name="Siva"` shouldn't even compile without error (or at least warning).

Comment: I am just trying to copy the value from name to str..But in first case it works properly...Why it give correct answer for first case...Please tell me that first

Comment: Not too sure why the first program doesn't give a segmentation fault either...

Comment: The first case works properly in g++ compiler...

Comment: You should accept an answer to this question. Click the checkmark next to the answer that you found most helpful for you (if helpful at all).

Answer (score 5):

```
char *name="Siva",*str;
for(int i=0;i<strlen(name);i++)
{
str[i]=name[i];
}
```

`str` is a pointer, but it doesn't yet point to anything.

Since you're in C++, you should be using `std::string`:

```
#include<iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;
int main()
{
  char *name="Siva";
  std::string str;
  for(int i=0;i<strlen(name);i++)
  {
    str += name[i];
  }
  cout<<str;
  return 0;
}
```

Even better, get rid of the hand-written loop:

```
#include <algorithm>
int main()
{
  char *name="Siva";
  std::string str;
  std::copy (name, name + strlen (name), std::back_inserter (str));
  cout<<str;
  return 0;
}
```

Better even still, there's no reason in this particular example why you need to do any of that at all:

```
char* name = "Silva";
std::string str = name;
cout << str;
```

By the way, string literals in C++ are inherently `const`:

```
const char* name = "Silva";
```

If you really must use a `char*`, first I would strongly question why, and then I would tell you to do this:

```
int main()
{
  const char *name="Siva";
  char* str = new char [strlen (name)+1]; // +1 for the null terminator
  strcpy (name, str);
  cout << str;
  delete [] str;
  return 0;
}
```

I would even more strongly question your need to copy it byte-by-byte:

```
int main()
{
  const char *name="Siva";
  char* str = new char [strlen (name)+1]; // +1 for the null terminator
  for (size_t i = 0; i < strlen (name); ++i )
    str [i] = name [i];
  str [strlen (name)] = '\0';
  cout << str;
  delete [] str;
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: I'll have to assume you're playing the pedant professor here: `std::copy (name, name + strlen (name), std::back_inserter (str))`. Come on

Comment: @sehe:  Yeah, just trying to show a few different ways to skin the cat.

Answer (score 3):

You have undefined behaviour here:

```
str[i]=name[i];
```

`str` has not been initialized to anything. You are writing to places you shouldn't.

Answer (score 3):

There are two problems with this.

1. The pointer `str` doesn't point to allocated memory, so writing through it is undefined behavior.
2. Even if it did point to valid memory, you're not writing the correct amount of data. When copying a string, you need to copy the `0` byte at the end which marks the end of the string; so the upper limit of your loop should bt `strlen(name) + 1`. Or you could use a library method like `strdup()` instead of your own `for` loop.

The reason the "working" version prints some garbage characters is that there's no `0` at the end of the copied string to tell `iostreams` to stop printing. The reason the "working" one doesn't crash, and the other one does, is pure dumb luck: the garbage in `str`, by chance, points to memory you're allowed to write to, while in the crashing program, it points to memory you're *not* allowed to write to. Simple as that.

Answer (score 2):

It is because you have no memory allocated for `str`. (it will cause an undefined behavior)

You can mix that by using a merory allocation function like in this example :

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    char *name="Siva",*str;
    // Allocate memory with malloc
    str = (char*)malloc( (strlen(name)+1) * sizeof(char) );
    for(int i=0;i<strlen(name);i++)
    {
        str[i]=name[i];
    }
    str[strlen(name)] = 0;
    cout<<str;
    // Free the allocated memory
    free(str);
    return 0;
}
```

As you are using c++, you can do :

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    char *name="Siva",*str;
    // Allocate memory with new
    str = new char[strlen(name) + 1];
    for(int i=0;i<strlen(name);i++)
    {
        str[i]=name[i];
    }
    str[strlen(name)] = 0;
    cout<<str;
    // Free the allocated memory
    delete []str;
    return 0;
}
```

**EDIT :**
The reason you have some weird caracters at the end of your ouput is that because you string is not terminated with a '\0', it will continue to print it. (This will occur only if you don't have a `segmentation fault` )

Comment: Then how it gives that answer

Comment: It is an undefined behaviour. Sometimes, the operating system will let your program access to that memory. But it is more common to end up with a `segmentation fault` ...

Comment: "You should do" - This must be some strange meaning of the word "should" that I was previously unaware of.

Comment: I changed it, you were right.

Answer (score 1):

`str[i]=name[i];` is illegal, causes Undefined behavior, because you have not allocated memory for `str`.

Before for loop allocate memory for destination string `str`:

```
str = malloc (strlen(name) + 1 );
```

Also you forgetting string termination,  after for-loop add terminate string `str[i] = '\0'`;
[**Undefined behavior**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) refers to computer code whose behavior is unpredictable.

You code should be:

```
char *name="Siva", *str;
str = malloc (strlen(name) + 1 ); // mistake 
for(int i=0;i<strlen(name);i++)
{
    str[i]=name[i];
}
str[i] = '\0';  // forgetting
```

To understand further you can read this answer: [strcat() implementation works but causes a core dump at the end](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16750998/strcat-implementation-works-but-causes-a-core-dump-at-the-end/16751011#16751011)

Comment: Then how it gives answer for first case......

Comment: It's undefined behavior. Anything can happen.

Comment: "Undefined" means "It might work, and it might not."

Comment: Actually, I think "it might work" is misleading. It might _appear_ to work. But _never_ actually (provably/reliably)

Comment: @sehe yes its worst case when program executes correctly even under undefined behavior

Comment: .... ugh. "executes correctly". No it doesn't. It might provide the visible output you expect, but that's only because humans don't look very closely.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple problems with your code.

Firstly, *str is not allocated, so it starts off by pointing to whatever bit of memory the pointer value happens to start off as.

Secondly, strlen() returns the length of the string excluding the terminating null character. So what you are doing is copying all the values of name into some random bit of memory, not terminating it, then telling the system to print that off, which could be any length.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is using char arrays and pointers to represent strings in language which has proper string type.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string name = "Siva", str;
    str = name;
    cout << str;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem is with `str[i]=name[i]` you must know that C++ does not care for [memory leaks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_leak)
as Java or some others. So you must allocate memory to a variable or pointer in order to avoid these problems. Already there are number of answers, you can also try

```
str=new char[strlen(name)+1];
```

and do not forget to terminate the char array with null when you done copy. In this case

```
str[strlen(name)]='\0';
```

Comment: You mention memory leaks, yet fail to mention `delete` which has to be called to avoid memory leaks :/ Also, if you're coming from Java, you may be surprised with the fact that C++ has a string type (`std::string`), which manages memory (RAII).

Comment: That is not the case. I know C++ more than Java. May be you are surprised when I was a student I was using Turbo C++, no String class, then I made a full string handling there by my self.

Comment: I know, and *I don't care* - I checked my calendar and saw it's now year 2013. Nevertheless, my point was you don't mention `delete[]` has to be used after `new[]`. Also, as you see, C++ evolves (`std::string` was added in *1998*), as well as its usage.