# How to know line with segmentation fault in my code?

Tags: c, pointers, segmentation-fault

I'm trying to learn C pointers these days, when I am trying to deal with string and pointers, and link list I am frequently getting segmentation errors. And I wasn't able to fix these issues (I can't find out the exact line where the segmentation fault is happening). My questions are:

1. What is the tool to find the line with the segmentation fault in my code?
2. Is there any material (book or tutorial) that you can suggest to me to know about all issues related to the segmentation faults, their reasons and solutions?

gdb output:

```
/home/sri/Documents/projects/practice/c/strings/a.out...done.
(gdb) run
Starting program: /home/sri/Documents/projects/practice/c/strings/a.out 
Missing separate debuginfo for /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
Try: zypper install -C "debuginfo(build-id)=ecb8ef1a6904a2a3ec60a527f415f520c8636158"
Missing separate debuginfo for /lib64/libc.so.6
Try: zypper install -C "debuginfo(build-id)=bd1473e8e6a4c10a14731b5be4b35b4e87db2af7"
this is print1 char *p 

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x00000000004005dd in do_print2 (p=0x7fffffffdda0) at string_orguments.c:16
16      strcat(p[0],"added");
(gdb)
```

Comment: @jxh `p` is actually an array of `char` pointers (from a related question).

Comment: I don't understand why "at string_orguments.c:16" doesn't tell you that the error is on line 16?

Comment: thanks Drew McGowen, that was the error at line 16. thanks alot

Comment: Don't change Question, Rollback to previous version.

Comment: Fixed... everything for you...

Comment: The thing is that you shouldn't be looking for "segmentation faults", which are the _symptom_ and are often fairly unpredictable. The _cause_ is poor/broken memory management -- look for that.

Comment: [most of reasons covered for segmentation-fault](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/segmentation-fault?sort=votes&pagesize=15)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As OS detects memory right violation by a process -- An invalid access to valid memory gives: `SIGSEGV`.

In output:

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
 0x00000000004005dd in do_print2 (p=0x7fffffffdda0) at string_orguments.c:16
 16     strcat(p[0],"added");
```

Shows at `strcat(p[0],"added");`  you are trying  to write on a memory that is for read only - invalid operation on valid memory.

Note: `strcat` function at very first step try to write char `a` from second argument string literal `"added"` at a position where `\0` is in `p[0]`. So you might getting the signal `SIGSEGV` because write operation is invalid in place of `\0` (possible writing on read only memory).

Also note: access to an invalid address gives: `SIGBUS`

Read: [strcat() implementation works but causes a core dump at the end](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16750998/strcat-implementation-works-but-causes-a-core-dump-at-the-end/16751011#16751011) To understand better.

Finding segmentation fault algorithmically  is Unsolvable problem, you don't have any tool (automation tool) for this purpose. But Only way it to bug your code using `gdb` like tools. 
Additionally to avoid segmentation fault read language principals/ruls precisely. You should be clear why segmentation fault occurs. then only by practice and experience you can learn How to write less buggy and more debuggable code.

Also you should understand segmentation fault happens at runtime. may be your code run fine for some set of values but not for some set of values. So segmentation can't be detected at compilation time like.

<sub>This also says why its unsolvable problem, because we can't write general algorithm that generates randomly infinite inputs and to test whether your code works perfectly!</sub>

Comment: @SrinivasThanneeru wait here, don't post similar question again/again ..wait I give you a related link.

Comment: @SrinivasThanneeru: finding segmentation fault allegorically is Unsolvable problem  you don't have any tool for this, but Only way it to bug your code using gdb like tools, Additionally to avoid segmentation fault read language principals precisely. You should be clear why segmentation fault occurs. then only by practice and experience you can learn to write bug free code.

Comment: I would change *write bug free code", to "write less buggy and more debuggable code".